# Memcached and repcached not replicating 2 master servers

Tags: centos5, high-availability, memcached

I have memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2 installed on memcached on centos.

They install went great and when i start memcached i get:

```
replication: connect (peer=192.168.1.2:11212)
replication: marugoto copying
replication: close
replication: listen
```

This looks good, but when I telnet from a 3rd server into the 1st server and store a key and a value, I can telnet into the 2nd server but `get key` just returns END.
What am I doing wrong here? I want a master-master setup so server 1 replicates changes to server 2 and vise versa.

Comment: Can you run the memcached in debug mode to get more details in the log file?

Comment: I like repcached. Is the version you've got "stable"?

Comment: I can only run with -v right?

Comment: You can try `-vv` (very verbose) if you want: `/usr/local/memcached/bin/memcached -d -u memcached -l 192.168.3.145 -c 2048 -t 8 -m 64 -p 11211 -P /usr/local/memcached/var/run/x.pid -f 1.25 -x 192.168.4.107 -X 112110 -vv > /var/log/repcached.log 2>&1`.